# Is there a python implementation of multidimensional ECDFs?

Tags: python, spatial, ecdf

Looking for a package that implements the multivariate version of `statsmodels.distributions.ECDF`

If one doesn't exist I will implement it for inclusion in statsmodels (if accepted), but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

I see this: https://gitlab.com/stochastic-control/StOpt

It has pybind11 bindings, but not sure if there is a wheel in pip already making this available.

Comment: GPL code is not license compatible with statsmodels.

Comment: Some python copula packages, might have empirical copula support that includes it.

Comment: @Josef good point about GPL — this library wouldn’t be usable in statsmodels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upcoming release of statsmodels 0.13 includes basic support for copulas.

Empirical and non-parametric copula and multivariate distributions have mainly experimental code, that is currently not public, and not sufficiently tested and verified.

For example `_ecdf_mv` (*) is currently a multivariate `rankdata` function. It needs to be divided by the number of observations or converted to plotting positions to make it into a ECDF. Because copulas require continuous uniform margins, ties are randomly or arbitrarily broken.

(*)
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/distributions/tools.py#L424

Comment: Thanks — this is great to hear it’s on your roadmap. Any estimate on target release?

Comment: The rc for 0.13 is out. release will be soon. But empirical Beta copula and support like ECDFMV will need to wait for 0.14. (I ran out of time for 0.13.)

Comment: excellent! Will monitor the updates :) is the plan to have ecdfmv implement the same interface as the univariate ECDF already in statsmodels.distributions?

Comment: I guess the one part that is computationally tricky is returning values between data points — the author of the code I linked to has a paper that outlines efficient methods for large datasets — worth a look: https://cs.paperswithcode.com/paper/fast-multivariate-empirical-cumulative

Comment: My usecase for this was in support of Beta copula. The points in between are essentially a kernel density or kernel cdf estimate. That is smoothed instead of a step function.

Comment: Would you be open to me providing a pure Python version of the algos in this paper for statsmodels or is that out of scope?

Comment: As long as it's license compatible, it will be very welcome. The plan is to add more support for multivariate distribution, now that statsmodels has the basic copula tools.

Comment: ok I’ll submit under modified BSD per the statsmodels dev docs

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a Multidimensional Divide-and-Conquer algorithm here: https://github.com/abockmann/Multidimensional-ECDF/blob/main/mdc.py
(Bentley, J. L. (1980). Multidimensional divide-and-conquer. Communications of the ACM, 23(4), 214-229.)
It computes the rank; just divide by the number of points, and you get the multidimensional ECDF.  Note that the execution time grows very fast with an increasing number of dimensions, but at least in two dimensions, it will significantly outperform brute-force for a large number of points.